# TextInput multiline: text overlay underline

Tags: react-native

I'm using `TextInput` with `multiline = {true}` in my react-native Android application. 
The last line of `TextInput` overlays on underline:

My reputation doesn't allow me to post image, so here is the `GIF` with example of my issue:

[My Link](https://media1.tenor.com/images/8008513ed3d9d0633cf3ce80409a7363/tenor.gif?itemid=13894958)

How can I avoid this?

```
 <TextInput
 multiline = {true} 
 numberOfLines = {2}
 underlineColorAndroid = {Colors.tintColor}/>
```

Comment: can u paste more code here ?

Comment: plz can you send your code for better understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this it works

```
  <TextInput
                          multiline = {true}
                          style={{ padding: 10,height: 45,}}
                          numberOfLines = {2}
                          underlineColorAndroid = {Colors.tintColor}
                      />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
       <Text style={{color:global.COLOR.ORANGE}}>hello</Text>
       <TextInput
       style={{width:200}}
       placeholder="name"
       underlineColorAndroid={global.COLOR.ORANGE}
                      multiline = {true}
                      numberOfLines = {2}

                  />
     </View>
```

you can try this